# react navigation how to pass navigation object to tabBarButton?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am using create Bottom Tab Navigator , version 6 , is there a way to pass navigation object from Tab.Screen to TabButton ?  taking in account props of tabBarButton  that I must also pass them to my custom component (TabButton) , here is my code thanks for your help :

```
 <Tab.Screen key={index} name={item.route} component={item.component} 
            options={{
              headerShown: false,
              tabBarButton: (props) => <TabButton {...props} item={item} />
            }}
          />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can pass `navigation` and `tabBarButton` props in this way,
The options function receives the navigation prop and the route prop for that screen, so you may also use route there.

```
 <Tab.Screen key={index} name={item.route} component={item.component} 
    options={({ navigation }) => ({
       headerShown: false,
       tabBarButton: (props) => <TabButton {...props} navigation={navigation} item={item} />
    })
  }
  />
```

Comment: this did not work with me

Comment: can you please share what issue you are facing after with this solution

Comment: you are right , it was a typo error :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's the example how you can do it

```
      <Stack.Screen
        name={"ComponentName"}
        component={ComponentScreen}
        options={(props) => {
          return {
            header: () => (
              <CustomHeaderComponent
                title={"SomeCoolTitle"}
                {...props}
              />
            ),
          };
        }}
      />
```

Comment: thanks @szymekk147 for your reply , in your example what if I want also pass props of header ? , I mean passing props of header and Stack to CustomHeaderComponent?

Answer (score 0):

I just added a global variable and affect  to it props.navigation , like so :

```
  return (
          <Tab.Screen key={index} name={item.route} component={item.component} 
            options={( props ) => {
              _navigation = props.navigation
              return{
                tabBarButton: (props) => <TabButton {...props} item={item} navigation={_navigation} />
              }
            }
          }
          />
        )
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).